# Unzip base64 and gzip code

Tags: python-2.7, base64, gzip, zlib

I've had a lot of issues with trying to decode a response I receive from the AWS Kinesis Streams API. Here is some sample code:

## Snippet

```
data = """\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x96\xdbN\xdb@\x10"""

import zlib
import base64

b64data = base64.b64decode(data)
print b64data
    # Result is 7��w�0 �b�����Ե~ނk�6Ι���`�`�����$���hoϭ�l���vd[�Y��Я�

unzipped2 = zlib.decompress(unzipped)

print unzipped2
```

Result is this error:

> errorTraceback (most recent call last)
>
> ```
>   <ipython-input-5-d626d7fd724e> in <module>()
>     6 unzipped = base64.b64decode(data)
>    7 print unzipped
>    ----> 8 unzipped2 = zlib.decompress(unzipped)
>    9 
>    10 print unzipped2
>
>    error: Error -3 while decompressing data: unknown compression method
> ```

Comment: what are you issues? What did you try to solve them? Why didn't they work?

Comment: That's gzip, not zlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `zlib.decompress(unzipped,31)` instead to decode your gzip-formatted data.